# Convert int to float in Java without rounding

Tags: java, rounding

I have int value `40959999`. How to  convert it to float without rounding into `409599,99`?

result of `float f = 40959999/100.00f`  will be `409600.0`

Comment: use double for more precision

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Use double instead of float

```
double d = 40959999/100.00f;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Double` and `Float` have inherent imprecision that is impossible to avoid (more info on the why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)). Using a double you may not have your number rounded in this scenario but not in all. If you work with something that should never be rounded (like prices), you should be using `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `int` value like shown. Rather than using `float` use `BigDecimal` instead.

```
BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.valueOf(40959999); 
int scale = 2;
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(b1, scale); 
System.out.println(d1);

run:
409599.99
```